# Is there an efficient way to calculate a weighted average of a series of variables' percentage value within different ranges?

Tags: javascript, function, range

I have four variables that have differing ranges.  I need to calculate the percentage position of each variable within its specified range and then calculate a weighted average of the percentiles.  Some weights are measured ascending and some descending.  Ascending means that the range percentage is higher as the variable increases above the minimum and descending means that the range percentage value increases as the variable decreases below the maximum value.

I am using ES5.

I have some brute force code, but this is not likely the most efficient solution?

Additional information:  The goal is to calculate a single number which analyzes the value of four variables.   For each variable, there is a range of values relevant to the situation being measured.  Additionally, each variable has a different weight to the final output.

```
function fCalcWtdAvg() {

//Four variables are the inputs: vVar1, vVar2, vVar3, vVar4
//For each variable, there is a relevant range and a weight
//For example, for vVar1, a value above 50 is relevant and a value at or above 100 is most significant, so 60 would be 20%, then weighted by vVar1Wt 

var vVar1Min = 50,  vVar1Max = 100, vVar1Wt = 0.1;                  
var vVar2Min = 0.3, vVar2Max = 0.5, vVar2Wt = 0.3;  //Note: descending      
var vVar3Min = 150, vVar3Max = 500, vVar3Wt = 0.5;                  
var vVar4Min = 0.8, vVar4Max = 2,   vVar4Wt = 0.2;  

//next calculate the percentage that the value of the variable is "in the range"

var vStress1 = fPercentRange(vVar1, vVar1Min, vVar1Max);
var vStress2 = fPercentRangeDec(vVar2, vVar2Min, vVar2Max);
var vStress3 = fPercentRange(vVar3, vVar3Min, vVar3Max);
var vStress4 = fPercentRange(vVar4, vVar4Min, vVar4Max);

return vWtdAve = (vStress1 * vVar1Wt) + (vStress1 * vVar1Wt) + (vStress1 * vVar1Wt) + (vStress1 * vVar1Wt);

}

function fPercentRange (vVal, vMin, vMax) {
// if a higher value is more significant

  if (vVal > vMin) {
    var vPercent = ((vVal - vMin) / (vMax - vMin)) * 100;
    return number = Math.min(parseInt(vPercent), 100);
  } else { 
    return 0;
  }
}

function fPercentRangeDec (vVal, vMin, vMax) {
//if a lower value is more significant 

    if (vVal < vMax) {
        var vPercent = ((vMax - vVal) / (vMax - vMin)) * 100;
    return number = Math.min(parseInt(vPercent), 100);
  } else { 
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Would appreciate some suggestions on achieving this more efficiently.

Comment: Please explain formula and/or algorithm

Comment: Zero - thanks, I have added more to description and comments to code.  Hopefully  this explains more clearly.

Comment: I've decided to mark my original post as the answer, but I'm not sure that I can do this?